# Why am I getting a return of index two?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

I can not understand why my return is index 2 and not index 0 in the for of loop.

```
function cardPicker() {
  let cards = [
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "J",
    "Q",
    "K",
    "A"
  ];
  for (p of cards) {
    return cards[p];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for ... of` loop iterates through the **values** of the array, not the indexes. Your loop therefore returns the value at index 2 in the array, the string "4". If you changed it to a `for ... in` loop, you'd get the string "2".  Of course, there's no point to the loop at all because the only thing the loop does is `return`, so it will exit on the first iteration.

Also `p` should be declared with `let` or `var`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know there is no point to the loop. I just had an issue in my entire code and this was an anomaly that I did not understand.

Comment: very interesting question, @pointy can you explain why this code not print all the values
function cardPicker() {
  let cards = [
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "J",
    "Q",
    "K",
    "A"
  ];
  for (let p of cards) {
    console.log(cards[p]);
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

p in your example will be "2", so you will return the index 2 of your array, which will returns "4".

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
for (p of cards) {
   return cards[p];
}
```

To this:

```
for (p in cards) {
   return cards[p];
}
```

Comment: It'll still return "2"

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm not 100% sure what the OP is asking to be honest.